# Function body not executed if not passed directly to requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, function

So I had this originally:

```
requestAnimationFrame(appendItemsFragment(itemsFragment, appendItemsFragmentCallback));
```

But I needed to do something more, so I transformed it to

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  appendItemsFragment(itemsFragment, appendItemsFragmentCallback);
  myNewFunctioncall();
});
```

Original function is defined as:

```
const appendItemsFragment = (itemsFragment, callback) => () => {
  itemsContent.appendChild(itemsFragment);
  destroySpinner();
  if (callback) {
    callback();
  }
};
```

But in the modified version of the **requestAnimationFrame**, the function **appendItemsFragment** is not executed (I put an alert() and it does not work, I press F10 two times and it comes back to the end of **requestAnimationFrame**). Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

`appendItemsFrament()` returns a callback function. In the original code, `requestAnimationFrame()` executes that callback. Now you need to do it in your wrapper function.

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  appendItemsFragment(itemsFragment, appendItemsFragmentCallback)();
  myNewFunctioncall();
});
```

However, this will call `appendItemsFragment()` for every frame that's displayed, which will repeatedly append the item fragment, which is probably not what you want. You need to call it once, save the result, and then call that in your wrapper function.

```
let callback = appendItemsFragment(itemsFragment, appendItemsFragmentCallback);
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  callback();
  myNewFunctioncall();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a hunch that it was something related to that haha